# Documents Directory for Android and IOS in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good Day currently I have an Idea to save my JSON file. But the problem is, I don't know how to create a path for the phone's Documents Directory?

In corona SDK, I use

```
system.pathForFile("filename.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
```

but in Unity I don't know how to do this. Still using PlayerPrefs though, but I find it hard to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Application.persistentDataPath` - this is the path you need.

[DOC](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)